Scalars that are both Additive and Multiplicative inverses on secp256k1
I believe I have found two scalars (a) and (b) that are both additive and multiplicative inverses on the secp256k1 elliptic curve.
So scalars (a) and (b) meet the following criteria:
$[ a + b \equiv 0 \ (\text{mod} \ n)]$
$[ a \cdot b \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ n) ]$
I've tried to find any references to such scalars but haven't found any. How rare are these scalars, and what are the implications, if any?
Edit:
n is the order of the secp256k1 curve: $n = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141$
If pick a point P on the curve, then using these scalers a and b the following holds true:
$⋅P + ⋅P = (point at infinity) $
$ ⋅⋅P = P $

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Not sure what you mean, but any pair $a,b$ satisfying that will be roots of the equation $z^2-0z+1=0 \mod n$, and so effectively can be thought of like $i$ and $-i$. Apparently $n$ is not the prime used in secp256k1, as that prime is $3 \mod 4$ which means there is no solution to that polynomial there.

In my case n is the order of the secp256k1 curve:
n = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141
So If pick a point on the curve P then using these scalers a and b
⋅P + ⋅P = (point at infinity)
and
⋅⋅P = P
